# Sorting in a Array List of HashMaps

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a data Structure as shown below:

```
public class VResultSetBean {
   private ArrayList<RowBean> rowBeans; 
}

public class RowBean {
    private HashMap<String, Object> columns;
}
```

I need to sort `rowBeans` based on value of one of the keys in HashMap `columns`. What is the most efficient way to do this with Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make `RowBean` implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and implement the `compareTo` method to pull out the value of that key and use it to decide the result of the comparison.

```
public class RowBean implements Comparable<RowBean> {

     private HashMap<String, Object> columns;

     @Override
     public int compareTo(RowBean other) {
          Object valOther = other.columns.get(...);
          Object valMine = columns.get(...);
          return comparison(valOther, valMine);
     }
}
```

Once `RowBean` is a `Comparable` you can sort using:

```
 Collections.sort(rowBeans);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the final code snippet that worked for me. Thanks guys..

```
public class RowBean implements Comparable<RowBean> {
         HashMap<String, Object> columns;
        public int compareTo(RowBean other) {
             Object valOther = other.columns.get("CONVERSIONS");
             Object valMine = columns.get("CONVERSIONS");
             return comparison(valOther, valMine);
        }
        private int comparison(Object valOther, Object valMine) {
           if((Long) valMine > (Long)valOther) 
                return 1;
            else if((Long) valMine < (Long)valOther)
                return -1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no way to compare two objects of class `Object`, they need to have a way to get compared: this is implementing the interface `Comparable`. so you would need to change `columns` to be `HashMap<String, Comparable>`.

After that, you could add a comparing method to `RowBean` like this:

```
class RowBean {

    private HashMap<String, Comparable> columns;

    public int compare(String column, RowBean other) {
        return columns.get(column).compareTo(other.columns.get(column));
    }

}
```

And finally, to sort your list you could use an anonym `Comparator`, this way:

```
List<RowBean> list = new ArrayList<>();

final String sortingColumn = "myColumn";

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<RowBean>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(RowBean o1, RowBean o2) {
        return o1.compare(sortingColumn, o2);
    }
});
```